# Getting error when trying to run python script using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

```
- name: Create directory for python files
  file: path=/home/vuser/test/
    state=directory
    owner={{ user }}
    group={{ user }}
    mode=755

- name: Copy python file over
  copy:
    src=sample.py
    dest=/home/vuser/test/sample.py
    owner={{ user }}
    group={{ user }}
    mode=777

- name: Execute script
  command: python sample.py
  args:
  chdir: /home/vuser/test/
  ignore_errors: yes
```

error
fatal: [n]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["python", "sample.py"], "delta": "0:00:00.003200", "end": "2019-07-18 13:57:40.213252", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-07-18 13:57:40.221132", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "1", "stdout_lines": ["1"]}

not able to figure out,  help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure your `sample.py` script doesn't produce any errors?

Comment: yes no errors, did run the file on the node once it is copied using python sample.py . sample.py has just printf statement

Comment: Try to change `ignore_errors: yes` to `ignore_errors: True` and remove the empty `args:`.

Comment: I have already removed ignore_errors: yes but if I remove args then I get errorERROR! 'chdir' is not a valid attribute for a Task

Comment: I see. `chdir: /home/vuser/test/` is supposed to be under `args`. You have to indent that line.

Comment: indent did not change the error                                                                             - name: Execute script
  command: python sample.py
  args:
        chdir: /home/vuser/test/

Comment: @user583088: vrdrv is right. chdir must be indented. This was the reason of the error: `ERROR! 'chdir' is not a valid attribute for a Task`. You claim `indent did not change the error`?! You should make the question current. I downvoted.

Comment: I am not sure how to make that issue current , but I have added the changed code and the error in answer for better visibility . so that I can get this issue resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the indent like below and remove ignore_errors.

```
- name: Execute script
  command: python sample.py
  args:
     chdir: /home/vuser/test/
  register: cat_contents

- name: Print contents
  debug:
     msg: "{{ cat_contents.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Can you post what is your `sample.py` script?

Comment: #Sample.py                                                                                                        import sys
print ("hello world")
exit(1)

Comment: if I am removing exit(1) I am able to run without errors but not able to see the print line hello world

Comment: I create another python script to write a file which did work well , but dont understand why I am not seeing print statements

Comment: exit 1 is error status. If you want to see the print message, you need to register and then use debug to see the message. I'm am updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Create directory for python files
  file: path=/home/vuser/test/
    state=directory
    owner={{ user }}
    group={{ user }}
    mode=755

- name: Copy python file over
  copy:
    src=/home/vuser/sample.py
    dest=/home/vuser/test/
    owner={{ user }}
    group={{ user }}
    mode=777

- name: Execute script
  command: python sample.py
  args:
     chdir: /home/vuser/test/
```

The sample.py is copied correctly in the destination folder at the node1 at dest=/home/vuser/test/
but the I get this error after I have done the change also

fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["python", "sample.py"], "delta": "0:00:00.002113", "end": "2019-07-19 10:59:53.7535351", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-07-19 10:59:53.358678548", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "hello world", "stdout_lines": ["hello world"]}